# Matrices' outputs in GAP

Tags: gap

Does anyone know whether is a function in GAP via I would be able to change elements of matrices over GF(2) to the form 0 and 1. need to say, in GAP, outputs for elements of matrices defined over GF(2) are in these form: Z(2)^0 and 0*Z(2). Is it possible to change these elements in the last step to 1 and 0 respectively?

Comment: `List(mat,IntVecFFE)`

Comment: Also, try `Display(mat)`, if you wish only to display the matrix `mat` in a readable form, but do not need to actually calculate a new matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends whether do you need this to view the result or to use it in subsequent code.

For viewing, see [" Vectors and Matrices"](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap3.html) from the GAP tutorial:

"A vector or matrix of integers can also be multiplied with a finite field scalar and vice versa. Such products result in a matrix over the finite field with the integers mapped into the finite field in the obvious way. Finite field matrices are nicer to read when they are `Display`ed rather than `Print`ed. (Here we write `Z(q)` to denote a primitive root of the finite field with $q$ elements.)"

For example,

```
gap> m:= [[1,-1, 1],
>         [2, 0,-1],
>         [1, 1, 1]];
[ [ 1, -1, 1 ], [ 2, 0, -1 ], [ 1, 1, 1 ] ]
gap> Display( m * One( GF(5) ) );
 1 4 1
 2 . 4
 1 1 1
gap> Display( m^2 * Z(2) + m * Z(4) );
z = Z(4)
 z^1 z^1 z^2
   1   1 z^2
 z^1 z^1 z^2
```

Otherwise, if `elm` is an element of a finite prime field, then `Int(elm)` returns the smallest nonnegative integer such that `elm = int * One( elm )`:

```
gap> l:=AsList(GF(5));
[ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0, Z(5), Z(5)^2, Z(5)^3 ]
gap> List(l,Int);
[ 0, 1, 2, 4, 3 ]
```

and `IntVecFFE` may be used to perform the conversion on rows. See `?IntFFE` in GAP for more details about `InfFFE` and `IntVecFFE`.

Comment: Was this useful for you? Please don't hesitate to ask further questions.